# IMAP with authentication set to none

Tags: email, imap

While adding a Mediacom email account into Apple Mail I referenced their page on IMAP settings https://supportstage.mediacomcable.com/print/1446, I noticed that authentication type for incoming email is set to none.  Does that mean anyone can access my email just by knowing my email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that means that the communication from your computer to the IMAP server is not encrypted.  You still need to send your username and password to the server, but it is visible to someone sniffing your network traffic.  I wouldn't recommend using that service.